# Smo user created stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, smo

When I try to get the list of stored procedures from db by using smo, it lists a lot of stored procedures even if the database is empty.

I want to be able to get a list of stored procedures that are not system procedures. `IsSystemObject` is not working.

```
ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
myserver = new Server(serverConnection);
Database mydb = new Database();
mydb = myserver.Databases[cmbDbname.Text];
string classGenerated = "";
foreach (StoredProcedure mystr in mydb.StoredProcedures)
{
    if (!mystr.IsSystemObject)
    {
        classGenerated += mystr.Name + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
spClassText.Text = classGenerated;
```

Here, when I remove the `!mystr.IsSystemObject` clause, it returns a lot of stored procedures, else does not return my stored procedure created as a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Schema-attribute like this:

```
if (mystr.Schema != "sys")
{
    classGenerated += mystr.Name + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
if (mystr.Owner != "sys") 
{
        classGenerated += mystr.Name + Environment.NewLine;
}
```